# How to add String values to nvd3 line chart x axis values?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, linechart, nvd3.js

I'm using nvd3 to create a bar chart in my angular js app. here is the script part

```
<script>
        var app = angular.module("nvd3TestApp", ['nvd3ChartDirectives']);

        function ExampleCtrl2($scope){
            $scope.exampleData2 = [
        {
            "key": "Series 1",
             "values": [ 
             ["2004",5],["2005",10],["2006",3],["2007",9],["2008",10],["2009",5]]
        }
    ];

    $scope.xFunction = function(){
    return function(d){
        return d[0];
    };
}

$scope.yFunction = function(){
    return function(d){
        return d[1];
    };
}

        }
    </script>
```

and here is the view div

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleCtrl2">
    <nvd3-line-chart
        data="exampleData2"
        id="xExample"
        width="550"
        height="300"
        showXAxis="true"
        showYAxis="true"
        x="xFunction()"
        y="yFunction()"
        tooltips="true">
            <svg></svg>
    </nvd3-line-chart>
</div>
```

How can I use strings like "aaa" "bbb" ... as x axis values. if I replace "2004" with a non numerical string it gives an error saying 
Error: Invalid value for  attribute transform="translate(NaN,0)"

Comment: You should add an additional label variable into your data, and then in xFunction customize chart view. If you need to change only couple labels, just specify it in function, without additional vars. See a small [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/QiBdW7?p=preview), but it uses another directive.

Comment: @krispo, it works, thanks. please put it as an answer and i'll mark it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can use chart xAxis format function as follows

```
chart.xAxis
.axisLabel('Date')
.tickFormat(function(d) {
 var label = scope.totalLoanAmountData[0].values[d].label;
 return label;
});
```

and then use your data as follows with label attribute.

```
scope.totalLoanAmountData=[{
                        "key": "name of line one",
                        "values":[
                {x:1,y:2, label:"label1"},
                {x:1,y:2, label:"label2"},
                {x:1,y:2, label:"label3"},
                {x:1,y:2, label:"label4"},
                {x:1,y:5, label:"label5"},
                {x:1,y:2, label:"label6"},
                {x:1,y:7, label:"label7"},
                {x:1,y:2, label:"label8"},
                {x:1,y:8, label:"label9"}]

                           },

                      {"key": "name of line two",
                        "values": [

                {x:1,y:8, label:"label1"},
                {x:1,y:2, label:"label2"},
                {x:1,y:2, label:"label3"},
                {x:1,y:6, label:"label4"},
                {x:1,y:5, label:"label5"},
                {x:1,y:2, label:"label6"},
                {x:1,y:8, label:"label7"},
                {x:1,y:2, label:"label8"},
                {x:1,y:2, label:"label9"}]

                      }];
```

Read [this blogpost](http://channagayan.blogspot.com/2014/08/adding-string-values-to-nvd3-line-chart.html) for more details.